# Is Mercy's damage boost applied on fire or on hit?

Tags: overwatch

Specifically with regards to non-hitscan characters, when is Mercy's damage boost applied? Does it take effect after shooting, or only after a projectile hits a target?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The information in this answer previously were based on testing from Closed and Open Beta.  It has now been deleted due to [new testing from other players in the community.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost__as/)

#### Mercy's damage boost is applied on hit.

However....

Mercy's damage boost needs to be toggled on the player when the enemy receives the hit. Meaning, it's fine if the projectile isn't boosted when it launches, but by the time it gets to the enemy the Mercy must be boosting the team member who fired it in order for the enemy to take extra damage.

The only 3 damage sources in-game that Mercy cannot boost are:

- Symmetra's Sentries
- Torbjorn's Turret
- Junkrat's Rip Tire

All other ults, including projectiles like Hanzo's Dragonstrike, or D'Va's Self-Destruct can be boosted otherwise.

Comment: This isn't quite what I thought they were asking, maybe I read it wrong. To check: if you're boosting Pharah when she fires, and stop before the missile hits, it still does extra damage?

Comment: It only matters when you fire the projectile. If you're damage boosted, the projectile is fired, and the damage boost is taken off, the project will retain the same damage boost and be subjected to relevant fall off damage, but subsequent shots will become unboosted until a Mercy can reboost you.

Comment: tl;dr/ELI5: You cannot damage boost a shot that has already been fired. Mercy needs to be boosting damage before the target ally shoots their gun/uses their ability.

Comment: N.B. A recent edit changed the example from _Pharah_ to _McCree_, in case the example makes no sense to you.

Comment: I have no idea who edited it and will roll it back since it clearly conflicts with intent

Comment: This answer is contradicted by testing described here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4ltlbu/mercys_damage_boost_works_on_almost__as/. Do you have any source for your claims?

Comment: Tested from Closed and Open beta

Comment: Now correct due to edit.

Comment: So wait... if I'm Pharah and I ult from like 50m away, as long as Mercy tags me with her damage boost before the rockets impact, they get boosted? That seems soooo counter-intuitive o_O