# Does Mercy's Damage Boost apply to Ana's healing?

Tags: overwatch

I know it's called [Damage Boost](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Mercy#Caduceus_Staff), but unlike other healers [Ana](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ana) is using her weapon to heal allies, so maybe it would increase her healing. Does anyone know how these two abilities affect each other?

Comment: Both interesting points- I may be able to test this. Shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: Why would the method of delivering the heal change the fact it's a heal and not damage?

Comment: @NathanK because it's from the same weapon that damages enemies, no other healer delivers that way. Seemed plausible in my head anyway

Comment: I'd be more interested to know Mercy's damage boost interacts with Ana's damage, since Ana's damage is DoT (damage over time).  Does the boost last the full DoT, or only while Ana is boosted?  If Ana attacks and _then_ gets boosted, does the DoT still get partially boosted?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft what your looking for may be answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265085/is-mercys-damage-boost-applied-on-fire-or-on-hit?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.**

Mercy's Damage Boost alternate-fire increases the damage as the damage event occurs. As Ana's projectile only heals or deals damage on contact, the projectile itself cannot be "boosted".

Furthermore, as Ana's damaging shots are damage-over-time based, we can compare this directly with Widowmaker's Venom Mine.

As we know, her Venom Mine deals 75 damage over 5 seconds [(source)](http://owinfinity.com/en/hero/widowmaker/). This means that, if a Mercy is boosting a Widomaker for only half the duration, half of the ticks are not boosted.

Using this logic, Mercy's damage boost on an Ana projectile striking a friendly target will not register as a damage event, thus the healing will not be boosted.

If the Asker requires, I can provide some quick footage displaying this when I am able to test with 3 other people.

Comment: The damage event clause is exactly what I'm looking for. Your logic makes sense, in-game testing is always nice but not required :P

Comment: I finally got to test this with others, and confirmed its accuracy

Comment: "the projectile itself cannot be "boosted"." - So mercy can't boost junkrat?

Comment: @Jake Mercy can boost Junkrat- but she needs to be boosting him the moment the projectile hits the target, not when it leaves the weapon. If she cancels her beam while the projectile is in flight, it will not increase the damage of the projectile when it strikes.

Comment: Ok: so similarly, Mercy can boost Ana's damage so long as the boost is applied as the DoT is ticking away health. Thanks! I had read in some places that Mercy couldn't boost Ana at all which didn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

Her alt fire is DMG boost. Damage is the key word, her DMG boost on Lucio and Ana will not effect their healing

Comment: From the wording it sounds like you're just guessing. Have you tested this in the game?

Comment: The difference on Lucio is his healing does not come from the same source his damage does.

Answer (score -3):

No, they don't with each other.

Comment: Just saying it doesn't work is a good answer. :( Might want to add a little bit more.

Comment: Well there's nothing else to add. There was testing done when she was released and it was confirmed it didn't work.